# Processing data with Reponse size of 70 mb in React

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net, user-interface

i have an api. From this api, data is returned to me with a reponse size of more than 70 mb. When I look at the developer tools from the network, I see the incoming data (Content-lenght) as full. But I can't print the data to the UI with REACT. I couldn't see the data in the UI even though I sent it compressed from the api.

If anyone has an idea for a solution on the subject, can they share it with me?

enjoy your work

```
function* getTasks() {
    const cancelTokenSource = axios.CancelToken.source();
    try {
        const { data } = yield call(api.getUserTasks, cancelTokenSource.token);
        yield put(actions.getTasksSuccess(data || undefined));
    } catch (error) {
        yield put(actions.getTasksSuccess(undefined));
        yield put(showSnackMessage({ message: error.toString(), variant: 'error' }));
    }finally{
        if (yield cancelled()) {
            cancelTokenSource.cancel('Cancelled because a new service');
        }
    }
}
```

Here I get the data in getUserTasks. i am sharing it.

```
export const getUserTasks = (cancelToken) => axios.get('/User/GetMyTasks', { cancelToken: cancelToken });
```

i am share

```
export const allMyTasksReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

switch (action.type) {
    case Types.GET_TASKS_REQUEST: {
        return {
            ...state,
            tasksLoading: true
        };
    }

    case Types.GET_TASKS_SUCCESS: {
        const draft = getTasksDraft();
        draft.allTasks = Object.entries({
            own: action.tasks?.Data || [],
            inQueue: action.tasks?.InQueue || [],
            delegated: action.tasks?.DelegationTasks || []
        }).flatMap(([who, tasks]) => {

            return tasks.map((task) => {

                const taskDataPropertyName = dataMap[task.TaskType];
                const taskData = task.TaskData[taskDataPropertyName];
                const taskPropertyName = propertyMap[taskDataPropertyName];

                if (taskData) {
                    const taskMetaName = `${taskPropertyName}Meta`;
                    const taskMeta = { ...draft[taskMetaName] };
                    const allTasksMeta = { ...draft.allTasksMeta };

                    task.who = who;
                    taskData.who = who;

                    if(who === 'own' && task.PoolID !== '')
                        taskMeta[`${who}CountHasPoolID`]++;

                    taskMeta[`${who}Count`]++;
                    taskMeta[`${who}Count${task.Status}`]++;

                    taskMeta[`total`]++;
                    taskMeta[`total${task.Status}`]++;

                    const isToday =
                        moment(task.AssignedDate).format('D MMM, YYYY') === moment().format('D MMM, YYYY');

                    if (isToday) {
                        taskMeta[`${who}TodayCount`]++;
                        taskMeta[`totalToday`]++;
                    }

                    Object.entries(taskMeta).forEach(([key, value]) => {
                        if (draft[taskMetaName][key] !== value) {
                            allTasksMeta[key]++;
                        }
                    });

                    draft[taskMetaName] = taskMeta;
                    draft.allTasksMeta = allTasksMeta;
                    draft[taskPropertyName] = [
                        ...draft[taskPropertyName],
                        {
                            ...task,
                            TaskData: {
                                [taskDataPropertyName]: taskData
                            }
                        }
                    ];
                }
                return task;
            });
        });

        return {
            ...state,
            ...draft,
            tasksLoading: false
        };
    }

    // TASK SELECTION
    case Types.ADD_TASK_TO_SELECTED_TASKS: {
        return { ...state, selectedTasks: [...state.selectedTasks, action.workItemId] };
    }

    case Types.REMOVE_TASK_FROM_SELECTED_TASKS: {
        state.selectedTasks.splice(state.selectedTasks.indexOf(action.workItemId), 1);
        return {
            ...state,
            selectedTasks: [...state.selectedTasks]
        };
    }

    case Types.SET_EXTERNAL_TASKS: {
        return {
            ...state,
            externalTasks: action.tasks
        }
    }
    case Types.SET_SELECTED_TASKS: {
        return {
            ...state,
            selectedTasks: action.selectedTasks
        };
    }

    // TAKE ASSIGMENT
    case Types.TAKE_ASSIGMENT_REQUEST:
    case Types.TAKE_ASSIGMENT_BULK_REQUEST: {
        return {
            ...state,
            processTakeAssigment: {
                ...initialState.processTakeAssigment,
                executing: true
            }
        };
    }
    case Types.TAKE_ASSIGMENT_SUCCESS: {
        return {
            ...state,
            processTakeAssigment: {
                executing: false,
                success: true,
                error: false
            }
        };
    }
    case Types.TAKE_ASSIGMENT_ERROR: {
        return {
            ...state,
            processTakeAssigment: {
                executing: false,
                success: false,
                error: true
            }
        };
    }

    case Types.RESET_PROCESS_TAKE_ASSIGMENT: {
        return {
            ...state,
            processTakeAssigment: initialState.processTakeAssigment
        };
    }

    // USER INFO CAMPAIGNS
    case Types.GET_AVAILABLE_USER_INFO_CAMPAIGNS_SUCCESS: {
        return {
            ...state,
            availableUserInfoCampaigns: action.payload
        };
    }

    case Types.RESET_AVAILABLE_USER_INFO_CAMPAIGNS: {
        return {
            ...state,
            availableUserInfoCampaigns: []
        };
    }

    case Types.SET_PAGE_SIZE: {
        return {
            ...state,
            pageSize: action.pageSize
        };
    }

    case Types.REMOVE_EXPENSE_TASKS_LIST: {
        state.expenseTasks = state.expenseTasks.filter((task) => task.WorkItemID !== action.workItemId);
        return { ...state };
    }
    case Types.REMOVE_PREAPPROVAL_TASK_LIST: {

        state.expensePreApprovalTasks = state.expensePreApprovalTasks.filter((task) => task.WorkItemID !== action.workItemId);
        return { ...state };
    }
    case Types.ADD_TASK_TO_SELECTED_TASKS: {
        return { ...state, selectedTasks: [...state.selectedTasks, action.workItemId] };
    }
    case Types.REMOVE_TASK_FROM_SELECTED_TASKS: {
        state.selectedTasks.splice(state.selectedTasks.indexOf(action.workItemId), 1);
        return {
            ...state,
            selectedTasks: [...state.selectedTasks]
        };
    }
    case Types.SET_SELECTED_TASKS: {
        return {
            ...state,
            selectedTasks: action.selectedTasks
        };
    }
    case Types.REMOVE_PAYMENT_TERM_CHANGE_REQUEST_TASK_LIST: {
        state.paymentTermChangingTasks = state.paymentTermChangingTasks.filter(
            (task) => task.WorkObjectID !== action.workObjectID
        );
        return { ...state };
    }
    case Types.REMOVE_MYINFO_TASK: {
        state.globalMyInfoTasks = state.globalMyInfoTasks.filter((task) => task.WorkItemID !== action.workItemId);
        return { ...state };
    }
    case Types.REMOVE_ABSENCE_TASK_LIST: {
        state.leaveRequestTasks = state.leaveRequestTasks.filter((task) => task.WorkItemID !== action.workItemId);
        return { ...state };
    }
    case Types.REMOVE_RD_MISSING_HOUR_TASK_LIST: {
        state.rdMissingHourTasks = state.rdMissingHourTasks.filter((task) => task.WorkItemID !== action.workItemId);
        return { ...state };
    }
    case Types.REMOVE_OVERTIME_TASK_LIST: {
        state.overtimeTasks = state.overtimeTasks.filter((task) => task.WorkItemID !== action.workItemId);
        return { ...state };
    }
    case Types.REMOVE_LOAN_REQUEST_TASK_LIST: {
        state.loanRequestTasks = state.loanRequestTasks.filter((task) => task.WorkItemID !== action.workItemId);
        return { ...state };
    }
    case Types.REMOVE_ANNUAL_LEAVE_RECONCILIATION_TASK_LIST: {
        state.loanRequestTasks = state.loanRequestTasks.filter((task) => task.WorkItemID !== action.workItemId);
        return { ...state };
    }
    case Types.REMOVE_INVOICE_LIST : {
        state.invoiceTasks = state.invoiceTasks.filter((task) => task.WorkItemID !== action.workItemId)
        return {...state};
    }
    default:
        return state;
}
```

};